# Bundle with wildcard not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bundle

I'm trying to implement MVC's Bundle concept where I want to store a couple of CSS files together. Unfortunately, adding a wildcard doesn't work. Using `IncludeDirectory` with a wildcard doesn't work either.

There's just an empty space where it should have included my stylesheets.

*BundleConfig.css*

```
bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/bundles/jquery-ui-css").Include("~/Content/jquery-ui-1.11.4/*.css"));
```

*_Layout.cshtml*

```
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/jquery-ui-css")
```

The folder exists and the CSS files exist as well. Why is it not finding them? I'm not getting any errors. This only works if I add file by file, but I want to use the wildcard technique, which would otherwise defeat its purpose.

Comment: did you try using include directory ?
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/jquery-ui-css")
    .IncludeDirectory("~/Content/jquery-ui-1.11.4/", "*.css"));

Comment: @Overmachine That's what I did, read my post :) I've tried everything

Comment: is "jquery-ui-1.11.4" your folder?

Comment: @Arvaan Yeah? I suspect it has to do with that the file names go like this `jquery-ui.structure.min.css`. Too many dots in the file name and the engine gets confused

Comment: yes. try this:
bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/bundles/jquery-ui-css").Include("~/Content/jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui-*.css"));

Comment: @Arvaan I tried that too but it gives you an error because the wildcard can only pertain to a prefix or a suffix (`.css`)

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake
try this: bundles.Add(new Bundle("~/bundles/jquery-ui-css").Include("~/Content/jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui-‌{version}.css"));
This will accepts all jquery-ui

Comment: make sure your folder doesn't contain all minified files.. if so, make sure you're not filtering out minified files

Comment: @JamieD77 I'm not sure I understand you? I use `Bundle` instead of `ScriptBundle` because I don't want it to minify the already minified files.

Comment: @silkfire if I read correctly you said you have the min files included? then these files will only be included when you build in release mode. i.e <compilation debug="false">in your Web.config.

Comment: in your registerbundles void, after all of your bundles.Add() calls add `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;` and see if your files get included...  Another option is to remove the `.min` part of the file names

Comment: @silkfire I had the same problem, thank a lot, and yes it's limitation of mvc framework so It cant apply * wildcard on files that has dots in thier names. I changed the name and it worked but has any solution been found yet for this issue ?? because it's really annoying, if not could it be reported to Microsoft as a bug?